# Display none result as default value with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a small web interface for MySQL database using PHP. One task is to allow users to be able to input a string into a text field and the system should return the name of any table that contains this string in its name. However, my problem is that, every time you enter in the web interface, it will by default display all the table names. Here is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<body>

<h1>This is H1</h1>

<?php

$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = xxx;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

?>

<?php
$search = $searchErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["search"])) {
        $searchErr = "Search keyword is required";
    } else {
        $search = test_input($_POST["search"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";}
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>

<h2>Search Keyword</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $search;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $searchErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form>

<?php
    echo '<h2> Search Result: </h2>';
    $searchSQL = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
                  WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE LOWER('%$search%') 
                  AND table_schema = 'xxx'";

    $result = $conn->query($searchSQL);

    echo '<form method="POST" action="show_columns.php">'; // opening form tag

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $table_name = $row['table_name'];
            echo "<input type='submit' name='table_name' value='$table_name' /> <br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo ' ';
    }

    echo '</form>'; // closing form tag
?>

</body>
</html>
```

For example, every time I enter the web end, the search result will display all the table names. I assume that it might take empty string as the search key word? Any ideas on how to get around with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, please use prepared statements and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to keep your code safe from [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Using `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` for database queries is not the right thing to do here and can damage your data. In particular, `htmlspecialchars` should *only* be used for displaying arbitrary data, as you do correctly with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

Comment: **A:** *Simple,* you need to use a conditional statement around your query.

Comment: ... `if(condition) { run the query }`

Comment: @tadman Can you explain why `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` would ever need running through `htmlspecialchars` I need to know as there appears to be a hole in my knowledge

Comment: @RiggsFolly As a general rule anything that could contain HTML characters needs to be escaped. That's the filename, and there's no guarantee it doesn't have something unusual in it like an angle bracket or a quote.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest solution, but I add a condition before executing the search queries

```
if ($search!='') 
  {$result = $conn->query($searchSQL);}
else {...}
...
```

and the problem is solved. Thanks for all your suggestions.